# Getting started with load testing web apps with VS2008 Team System

Tags: visual-studio-2008, testing

Good afternoon, Everyone.
Do you have any recommendations for materials (videos, books, tutorials) that would help me get started with load testing web apps? I have VS2008 Team System and will need to use the tools available in there. No third party stuff or online load testing tools.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Test Edition Video Series](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb507749.aspx).  A good starting place would be the video titled "How Do I: Use the Visual Studio Team System Test Load Agent?"

-begin shameless plug-

And if you are interested in some more formal training, my company offers public training on the tool: [VSTS intro class](http://www.rttsweb.com/training/courses/vsts_pt_intro.jsp)

-end shameless plug-